# Error building Alfresco CE 5.0a in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, alfresco

I am trying to build Alfresco CE 5.0a in Eclipse.I followed steps according to this [link.](http://robferguson.org/2014/07/13/how-to-build-alfresco-using-subclipse-and-maven-on-osx-mavericks/) The checkout was successful.But while building the sourcecode using maven(using **clean install**) I am getting the following error.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project alfresco-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.alfresco:alfresco-core:jar:5.0.a: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.0.4-alfresco-patched, org.springframework.extensions.surf:spring-surf-core-configservice:jar:1.2.1-M16, org.springframework.extensions.surf:spring-surf-core:jar:1.2.1-M16, org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE, javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.0.4-alfresco-patched from/to alfresco-public (https ://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public): No response received after 60000 -> [Help 1]`

I guess this is because of this jar file under the Alfresco Core 5.0.a

`Downloaded: http ://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar`

I couldn't find that jar file in the specified URL.

So how can I solve this.Can I change the dependancy in pom.xml?
Help Needed.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not related to mockito.Try again. It seemed to me that the repository was temporarily unavailable. I can find the missing jar at https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mybatis/mybatis/3.0.4-alfresco-patched/

Comment: Why are you trying to recompile 5.0.a, and not a newer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Question Will be ,Why you would like to compile alfresco source code?Are you aware that We can do many customization without customizing alfresco source code.
Above was only for your information.

First try to compile it without using eclipse.Due to that you are facing error.

If still problem persist, remove dependencies from your .m2 directory of your maven and make maven download this dependencies again.If you face similar error again for different jar than remove it from .m2 and again fire clean install command.

This will definitely solve your problem.

**It may be that , above mentioned error is listing your all corrupted jar files so remove first and try it again**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.My objective is to customize alfresco dms and integrate it with an another s/w that we are building.So can you suggest a better way rather than building it from svn repo?